# Under What Conditions is $\prod_{n\in S}n^{1/n}\sim \prod_{n\in S}n^{1/|S|}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $S\subset \mathbb{N}$. Under what conditions would we have that
$$\prod_{\substack{n\in S \\ n\le x}}n^{1/n}\sim \prod_{\substack{n\in S \\ n\le x}}n^{1/|\{n\in S\;:\; n\le x\}|}\;?$$
Here $f\sim g$ means $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=1$. If it helps at all, my specific consideration is when $S$ is of density zero, i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty}|\{n\in S\;:\; n\le x\}|/x=0$. Messing around with the relation we see that the above requires that
$$|\{n\in S\;:\; n\le x\}|\sim \frac{\sum_{\substack{n\in S \\ n\le x}}\log n}{\sum_{\substack{n\in S \\ n\le x}}\frac{\log n}{n}}.$$
It may be that this is the simplest criterion.

As a note, the set of prime numbers satisfies this. This is because
$$\sum_{p\le x}\frac{\log p}{p}\sim \log x\qquad \text{(Merten's First Theorem)}$$
$$\sum_{p\le x}\log p\sim x\qquad \text{(Chebyshev's Function)}$$
$$\pi(x)\sim\frac{\log x}{x}\qquad \text{(Prime Number Theorem)}$$
I am wondering if there is a simpler general condition for the above, since that would tell us that the first two above relations imply the third.

Comment: Did you try to see if this works for prime numbers using the asymptotic $p_n \sim n \log n$?

Comment: It does work for prime numbers which is where it came up. I was wondering if there is a good general criterion. For prime numbers you can use Merten's first theorem, asymptotics on Chebyshev's function, and the prime number theorem.

Comment: I am sorry to nitpick, but what you wrote in your edit is not sufficient to prove your claim. Namely, you need more than these equivalents for the asymptotic equivalence to be preserved when you take the  exponential. You need to go at least to order $o(1)$.

Comment: @ClementC. Ah thank you. I'm only interested in the weaker claim of taking the log of both sides anyways, I just thought the product looked more manageable.

Comment: @ClementC. can you please write out what the proof you suggest to $o(1)$ would look like, if it works?

Comment: @kodlu I am not saying I know how to get it.  I an saying that exponentiation wouldn't preserve the equivalence, unless we have matching expansion up to o(1).